# Django group by and aggregate with weights

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

I have a table like this, that I interact with using Django ORM.

```
date                car_crashes         city
01.01               1                   Washington
01.02               4                   Washington
01.03               0                   Washington
01.04               2                   Washington
01.05               0                   Washington
01.06               3                   Washington
01.07               4                   Washington
01.08               1                   Washington
01.01               0                   Detroit
01.02               2                   Detroit
01.03               4                   Detroit
01.04               2                   Detroit
01.05               0                   Detroit
01.06               3                   Detroit
01.07               1                   Detroit
```

I want to know how many car crashes for each day happened in the entire nation, and I can do that with this:

```
Model.values("date") \
.annotate(car_crashes=Sum('car_crashes')) \
.values("date", "car_crashes")

date  car_crashes
1.01            1
1.02            6
1.03            4
1.04            4
1.05            0
1.06            6
1.07            5
1.08            1
```

Now, let's suppose I have an array like this:

```
weights = [
    {
        "city": "Washington",
        "weight": 1,
    },
    {
        "city": "Detroit",
        "weight": 2,
    }
]
```

This means that Detroit's car crashes should be multiplied by 2 before being aggregated with Washington's.

My solution would be to aggregate all different weights separately, multiply by the weight either with Pandas or SQL and then do the aggregation. This would be inefficient and slow (many queries at best, using Pandas at worst).

Is it possible to do it with a single ORM query or a SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions) to determine the weight value within the query, and that means you can firstly construct the `Case` expression:

```py
from django.db.models import IntegerField

when_list = [When(city=w['city'], then=w['weight']) for w in weights]
case_params = {'default': 1, 'output_field': IntegerField()}

Model.objects.values('date') \
    .annotate(
        weighted_car_crashes=Sum(
            F('car_crashes') * Case(*when_list, **case_params)
    ))
```